# Python import module/function from below subdirectory or anywhere

Tags: python, function, module

I would like to load in a function/module with my working directory as project main directory but the function file is store below the a subdirectory level so the normal

`from function_file import function_name`

does not work.

This is what the project directory set up looks like:

```
└───project_main_directory
    │   .gitattributes
    │   .gitignore
    │   README.txt
    │
    ├───code
    │   ├───exploration
    │   └───scripts
    │       │   script1.py
    │       │   script2.py
    │       │   script3.py
    │       │
    │       └───functions
    │           │   function1.py
    │           │   function2.py
    │           └───__init__.py
    │
    ├───data
    │   └───example_data
    │           data.csv
    └───documents
```

So I tried to import functions via

`import code.scripts.function.function1 from function1`

and that doesn't work. I know it's because the other subdirectories aren't modules, but I want to ask if there is away around that?

-- EDIT
I'm working from .py file in code/scripts/script1.py but working directory is project_main_directory/

Comment: where are you calling that code? I mean in what file?

Comment: what does this have to do with R? why have you tagged R and RStudio?

Comment: from code/scripts/script1.py but working directory is project_main_directory/

Comment: i removed r tag - sorry for confusion

Answer (score 1):

Add an empty file `__init__.py` to **every** subdirectories to make them as modules.

```
.
├── code
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── scripts
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── script1.py
└── main.py
```

Then if you have a function called `hello` in `code/scripts/script1.py` you can import that function by:

```
from code.scripts.script1 import hello
hello("yo")
```

Comment: I get error: ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'code.scripts'; 'code' is not a package``` even after added __init__.py to every subdirectory

Comment: @OliverOliver Note it is double _, __init__.py。I‘ve tested it both on Python2 and Python3. Could you check it again in a new project  with same folder structure in my answer?

Comment: yes i added ```__init__.py``` to each subdirectory and still get same error

Comment: Oh I see you edit. If  you are working on code/scripts/script1.py, just `from function import function1` should works.

Comment: Yes, but the working directory is ```project_main_directory```

Comment: In python, there is no "working directory" to constrain a project's "root". Where the code file is, there is the "working directory" of that code.

Comment: OK, I didn't know this. I'm used to R where there is a working directory and that is set the project directory and subdirectories contain code and data but paths are always relative to the main project directory

Comment: My solution was with respect to project_main_directory being your current directory. It depends on the IDE you are using. In Jupyter it is the directory of your .py file. In Spyder you can set your working directory. (similar to R)

Answer (score 0):

If your current directory is project_main_directory, you can use:

```
from code.scripts.functions.function1 import function1
```

Directory of your script doesn't matter. Only your current directory matters (refer top of the IDE)

Comment: I get error ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'code.scripts'; 'code' is not a package```

Comment: Just to clarify: 'code' is a directory? Python is case sensitive, so in case there are any CAPS please be careful.

Comment: My solution was with respect to project_main_directory being your current directory. It depends on the IDE you are using. In Jupyter it is the directory of your .py file. In Spyder you can set your working directory. (similar to R). Your question should have included the IDE you are using.

Answer (score 0):

To import function/module from another python file, you have to do something like below -

```
from code.scripts.functions.function1 import function1
```

Above we are loading *function1* from *function1.py* file which is stored in *functions* directory which is stored in *scripts* directory and finally in *code* directory.

EDIT - so you are saying, you want to load a function from function1.py in script1.py? In that case `from .functions.function1 import function` should work.

Comment: I get error: ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'code.scripts'; 'code' is not a package```

Comment: if you are at project_main_directory then, `.code` use (.) dot at the start

Comment: That gives this error ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.code'; '__main__' is not a package```

Comment: this should work if you are trying to load function/module from the project_main_directory. Also in project_main_directory should have python file where you are loading function/module.

Comment: Oh the python file I'm loading the function in from is NOT in project_main_directory

Comment: so you are saying, you want to load a function from function1.py in script1.py? In that case `from .functions.function1 import function` should work.